# Property Transfer In Soap Ui

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I want to transfer a specified tag value from the Soap Ui API response to the groovy script in the same test case.I have tried the property transfer between these two but the whole data from response is pasted in the groovy.Can anyone suggest me some better Idea.Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample response?

Answer (score 0):

Explaining this with a sample `xml` as there isn't your sample provided.

On executing a request, below is the response xml :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
         <ConversionRateResult>0.005</ConversionRateResult>
      </ConversionRateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now, will show you how to retrieve `ConversionRateResult` element value and made it available to access in other test steps.
The key is to store the value of the given element at test case level custom property using `Script Assertion` for the request step of the test case and able to accessit using `property expansion`.

**Script Assertion:**

```
//Check if the response is not empty
assert context.response

//Closure to get the any element value(non-repeting)
def searchData = { data, elementName ->
    data.'**'.find{ it.name() == elementName}
}

//Create object for the response
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Call the above closure to get the value of ConversionRateResult which is 0.005 in above response
log.info searchData(parsedXml, 'ConversionRateResult')

//Store it at test case custom property called RATE
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('RATE', searchData(parsedXml, 'ConversionRateResult') as String)
```

How to access RATE in following test steps of the same test case using property expansion?

- If the test step is of `Request` type step, then use `${#TestCase#RATE}`. For instance you have to access RATE value in next soap or rest or http or jdbc requests, then `<element>${#TestCase#RATE}</element>`
- If the test step is of `Groovy Script`, then use one of the below:
  `context.expand('${#TestCase#RATE}')` or
  `context.testCase.getPropertyValue('RATE')`